# Ruby Sinatra attachment

Tags: ruby, sinatra, attachment

I have a sinatra application that sends a file to the user when they click a file, I don't want to give an extension, but Sinatra or the browser is giving it "test.html"

```
attachment("test")
response.write("write test data")
```

how can I give the file name of test to the user without it getting renamed to test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be something the browser is doing, based on the MIME type being passed to it by Sinatra.

Extensions are significant on Windows, Mac OS and Linux OSes these days, so that value is helpful for the user and their machine's OS. Maybe you can improve things by providing a hint about the actual type of content being sent.

Sinatra's "[MIME Types](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Mime%20Types)" documentation says:

> When using send_file or static files you may have mime types Sinatra doesn’t understand. Use mime_type to register them by file extension:

```
configure do
  mime_type :foo, 'text/foo'
end
```

> You can also use it with the content_type helper:

```
get '/' do
  content_type :foo
  "foo foo foo"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, I was using this for a PEM file, so I just called it like this: content_type :pem (no extension)